# How to add a Number of arrays to the displayed text

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```js
this.MyMenu = function(){
      this.MyMenu = function(){
                
                
     for(i = 0; i < vis.Labels.length; i++)
      {        
              text(vis.Labels[i].name, 100, 50 * i+80);
             
      }
     };
```

I have written a for loop that iterates over the array stored in the Labels property of the vis object, which itself is kept in the global vis variable defined in sketch.js, writing each Labels property to the screen. Mymenu is displayed when I press the space bar and it looks as follows:

Select a Library:

Washington

Moscow

Beijing

I would like, however, that a number of the array was also displayed in the following manner, e.g.

1: Washington

2: Moscow

3: Beijing

I was trying to use IndexOf +1 but with no luck so far. Do you have any tips on how this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance
Andy

Comment: In the for loop, `i+1` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply use template literals to do this

```
this.MyMenu = function(){                
   for(i = 0; i < vis.Labels.length; i++)
    {        
      text(`${i+1}: ${vis.Labels[i].name}`, 100, 50 * i+80);
    }
};
```

OR

use string concatenation

```
this.MyMenu = function(){                
   for(i = 0; i < vis.Labels.length; i++)
    {        
      const index = i+1
      text( (index+ ": " + vis.Labels[i].name) , 100, 50 * i+80);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Many thanks Hemant. Much appreciated. I used the second option with string concatenation and it worked like a charm!